# What I know is that I×R is always subtracted from EMF but here in this article, it's saying something elese

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity, electric-circuits

Please explain me the first point. 
What exactly I need to know is; that the product of current and internal resistance is subtracted or added? Explain the reason also.
E-IR   Or E+IR ?
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! All the answers are really helpful. This is the best website.

Answer (score 3):

The text is addressing two different situations. Both formulas are correct, each to a different situation.

If the current $I$ is flowing **in the same direction** as the emf of the cell, then there is a potential drop $Ir$ across the internal resistance $r$ and a potential **increase** of $E$ across the cell. The current enters the cell at the -ve terminal and comes out at a higher potential at the +ve terminal. So the terminal PD is $V=E-Ir$. This would happen if there are no other sources of emf in the circuit.

If the current $I$ is flowing **in the opposite direction** to the emf of the cell, then again there is a potential drop $Ir$ across the internal resistance $r$ but now there is also a potential **drop** of $E$ across the cell. This is because current is flowing **backwards** through the cell, against the direction in which the cell is trying to drive the current. Current flows in at the +ve terminal and comes out at a lower potential at the -ve terminal. The terminal PD is now $V=-E-Ir=-(E+Ir)$. This would happen if there are other sources of emf in the circuit which are stronger than the emf of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

In a lot of cases it is convenient to represent a real cell as a series combination of an ideal cell of emf $\mathcal E$ and a resistor of resistance $R$.

For a resistor the potential at the node **A** where the current $I$ enters the resistor is always higher than the potential at the node **B** where the current leaves the resistor by an amount $IR$.
I have shown this as the left potential $V$ diagram below.

[image]

For a cell of emf the positive terminal **C** is always at a higher potential than the negative terminal **D** by an amount $\mathcal E$ which is the emf of the cell.

The left diagram below shows what happens if the current enters the positive terminal of a real cell (cell being charged) and the right hand diagram shows what happens if the currents leaves the positive terminal of a real cell (cell being discharged).

[image]

For the left hand diagram the current enters at node **E** and the potential drops by $IR$ going through the resistor and then drops again by $\mathcal E$ whilst going through the ideal cell to reach node **F**.
So the potential difference across the real cell is $\mathcal E + IR$ with the potential of node $E$ being higher than the potential of node **F** by $\mathcal E + IR$.

For the right hand diagram the current leaves at node **G** and the potential rises by $IR$ going through the resistor and then drops by $\mathcal E$ whilst going through the ideal cell to reach node **H**.
So the potential difference across the real cell is $\mathcal E - IR$ with the potential of node $G$ being higher than the potential of node **H** by $\mathcal E - IR$.

So if a real cell is discouraging the potential difference across it is $\mathcal E - IR$ and if the cell is being charged the potential difference across it is $\mathcal E + IR$.

Answer (score 0):

> the product of current and internal resistance is subtracted or
>   added?

Succinctly, there are two cases:

(a) If the source is *supplying*$^1$ power to the external circuit, subtract.

(b) If the source is *receiving*$^2$ power from the external circuit, add.

$^1$The source is supplying power if the current out of the $+$ terminal is *positive*

$^2$ The source is receiving power if the current out of the $+$ terminal is *negative*.

---

> Explain the reason also

Here's an intuitive way to see why this must be:

(1) The internal resistance can only dissipate energy and so, if the emf source with internal resistance is supplying power, the circuit must be receiving *less* power than it would if the internal resistance were *zero* .

(2) The power supplied to the circuit by the source is the product of the terminal voltage and source current

(3) So it must be that the terminal voltage is *less* than the emf when the source is supplying power to the circuit.